# Difference Between WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-farm

I'm new to SP farm administration and the farm architecture is still somewhat confusing to me.  The farm I've inherited contains one DB server and two WFEs (webA and webB).  I do not really understand webB's role.  webA seems to be the primary WFE.  If I go to central admin (http ://webA:12345) and look at my site collection list, all of site collections and web apps are listed on webA.

In IIS, the two look mostly redundant, with a few exceptions.  The Central Admin site is only on webA, and there is a workflow piece only running on webB.  However, if I restart/shut down webA, users cannot browse to SharePoint at all, so webB is not picking up in any redundant capacity.  If I click browse on the sites in IIS on web, it returns a 401 Unauthorized.

Can anyone help or point to any resources that will shed some light on what exactly is the role of the second WFE?

Answer (score 0):

From your description looks like Web A server is hosting all the Web applications and cental admin site. It is also serving the content to the end user.

If you dont have the Load balancer in place then it will not automatically redirect traffic from WEB A to Web B.

Couple of things to check to identify the role of each server.

- From Central Admin check **Servers in Farm**, from here you will which service is running on which server.
- also check the AAM and which server is being used for wfe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the WebA server is where the Central admin is hosted and is the Application server.

If you need the Central admin on WebB run the Product configuration wizard . When the Wizard runs click on Advanced settings and [select host web site.](http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx)

The harber.net link is for sharepoint 2007 but it stills works for all sharepoint versions.

It seems you have a three tier architecture. This [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2131832) would give you better picture about sharepoint architecture.

WEbB- The  Web Front end server 
This server is usede only to handle the incoming requests

WebA- Application Server which hosts the entral admin and the service applications
all the service applications like BCS, search etc.  are installed on these application server

DB- Database server

What you really need is to provide resilience for each tier.

Central admin ->Server in Farm - It provides a list of all the servers

Also check the alternate access mapping (AAM's) for ther web applications.

Check the best practices for [3 tier architecture](http://nikpatel.net/2013/03/20/new-best-practices-for-sharepoint-2013-farm-design-streamlined-topology/)